# Aligning html elements in a row in their parent container with css

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `div`s, one outer, and 3 inner `div`s that I want to align in the same row inside the main `div`. By default the `div`s are stacked one on top of another inside the main `div`, so I used `float` to make them appear in a row.

But once adding `float`, the `div`s no longer appear inside the main `div`. How can I line up the 3 `div`s inside that main `div` using CSS?

```html
<div id="main" style="border: solid 1px black;float:left;">
  <div id="left" style="border: solid 1px red;">
    Left
  </div>
  <div id="middle" style="border: solid 1px green;">
    Middle
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="border: solid 1px blue;">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you forget to clear the float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIV standard display is block. You need to change the outer DIV to display: flex.
The standard behavior of display flex is to put the child DIVs  in a row.

If you want to centralize them in the vertical and horizontal axis, you can use along display: flex, align-items: center and justify-content: center.

Float is used when you want to position an image near a text. Don't use this type of position for this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), simple and modern way to create layouts, like so:

```css
#main{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="border: solid 1px black;">
    <div id="left" style="border: solid 1px red;">
      Left
    </div>
    <div id="middle" style="border: solid 1px green;">
      Middle
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="border: solid 1px blue;">
      Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `display:flex;` in your parent div.

```html
<div id="main" style="border: solid 1px black;float:left;display:flex;">
    <div id="left" style="border: solid 1px red;">
    Left
    </div>
    <div id="middle" style="border: solid 1px green;">
    Middle
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="border: solid 1px blue;">
    Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` with `flex: basis: 100%;` on each `flex-item` to have the inner divs span the full width. If you just want them to be next to each other and not span the full width of the row you can use `inline-flex`.

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
}

#left,
#middle,
#right {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="border: solid 1px black;">
  <div id="left" style="border: solid 1px red;">
    Left
  </div>
  <div id="middle" style="border: solid 1px green;">
    Middle
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="border: solid 1px blue;">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```